# I'm working on openslide for wholeslide images of .svs file i try to run the code getting memory error

Tags: python, out-of-memory, openslide

working on openslide wholeslide images of .svs data

it was a big set of data loaded in machine and working fine upto 50% and getting memory error, My machine is 64bit 16gb ram

i tired to resize the .svs file, need to know how to resize and solve memory error

Comment: Using openslide, since generally, the slides could be very huge, the idea is that you could first set the area of interest and read and load only those parts. With openslide, you could read the info (including size)before reading whole slide. then first read the size, and select the region as big as it could fit then read image. read_region(location, level, size)

Comment: can you share any openslide related article

Comment: also usually for very big image, lower downsampled versions are stored as differene levels.

Comment: https://openslide.org/api/python/ here is the doc for openslide

Comment: import os
tile_dir = r"C:\Users\wholeslide_images\tiles"
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        tile_name = os.path.join(tile_dir, '%d_%d' % (col, row))
        print("Now saving tile with title: ", tile_name)
        temp_tile = tiles.get_tile(16, (col, row))
        temp_tile_RGB = temp_tile.convert('RGB')
        temp_tile_np = np.array(temp_tile_RGB)
        plt.imsave(tile_name + ".jpg", temp_tile_np)
        
this is my tiles saving code

Comment: I see in code you are using the get_tile with address, have you set the tile_size if you are using the get_tile and sure you are not reading with overlap over and over ?

Comment: no haven't set the tile_size how to do?